# How to read value in crossdomain?

Tags: javascript

I have two applications in two different domain (e.g, www.abc.com and www.abd.com) 
In first application i have a button. On click of this button I have to pass some value from www.abc.com to www.abd.com.

Note: Due to some reason there is no concept of iframe in any of these application. So we can not go with Window.PostMessage().

I have tried with cookies value, but this is also domain specific. I also tried to store the value in clipboard using JavaScript.

Please help me if any other options I have available for this cross domain message passing.

Comment: Read about CORS mechanism

Comment: Repost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: Do you own/manage both domains?  How are the two domains linked on the page?

Comment: You could just use a link and put the value in the query string.